# How to get getitem if found or not Dynamodb in Android

Tags: android, amazon-dynamodb

I am having an issue with my Android code where I am reading from Dynamodb using the SDK I want to read an Item using getItem which works but I want to do it if Item is found make a Toast msg "Item is found" and if not found with a toast msg "no item found. in the DynamoDBManager class the file is ok somehow I need to get that info in my Activity class

```
public static WinTicket getTicketByBarcode(String barcodeNumber) {

    AmazonDynamoDBClient ddb = Barca.clientManager.ddb();
    DynamoDBMapper mapper = new DynamoDBMapper(ddb);

    try {
        WinTicket winTicket = mapper.load(WinTicket.class,
                barcodeNumber);

        if(winTicket == null){

           String awo = "false" ;
            Log.e(TAG,"NOT FOUND");
            // No item found
        }
        else{

            String awo = "true" ;

            Log.e(TAG,"YES FILE IN DATABASE");

            // Item is found in database
        }







        return winTicket;

    } catch (AmazonServiceException ex) {
        Barca.clientManager.wipeCredentialsOnAuthError(ex);
    }

    return null;
}
```

the above code is DynamodbManager class

the one under here is from the Barca Activity class
I think in the Activity file I need to make some edit I dont know what but I sure its in the private class DynamoDBManagerTask or protected void onPostExecute

```
private class DynamoDBManagerTask extends
        AsyncTask<DynamoDBManagerType, Void, DynamoDBManagerTaskResult> {

    protected DynamoDBManagerTaskResult doInBackground(
            DynamoDBManagerType... types) {

        DynamoDBManagerTaskResult result = new DynamoDBManagerTaskResult();

        result.setTaskType(types[0]);

        if (types[0] == DynamoDBManagerType.GET_BARCODE) {

            user = DynamoDBManager.getTicketByBarcode(winnum);
            Log.e(TAG,winnum);


        }

        return result;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(DynamoDBManagerTaskResult result) {
        //  pdia.dismiss();

        if (result.getTaskType() == DynamoDBManagerType.GET_BARCODE) {

            if (datafound.equalsIgnoreCase("true")) {
                Log.e(TAG,datafound);


                Toast.makeText(Barca.this, "Item found",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

         else if (datafound.equalsIgnoreCase("false")){
                Log.e(TAG,datafound);


                Toast.makeText(
                    Barca.this,
                    "Sorry no Item found",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: After some days of trying I got a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to use and If statement in protected void onPostExecute(DynamoDBManagerTaskResult result) section

```
if user == null { 
                   //item not in database 
                 }

           else {   
                  // item in database 
                 }
```